# csv import into django models

Tags: python, django

My python csv import script creates an extra empty entry in the database model every time I load data. I have tried to work around various ways but I still get one empty entry plus the actual data am loading from the csv.Here is what my script is like. Please your help will be of great achievment.

```
class CsvUploadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
form_class = CsvAttendeeForm
template_name = 'attendee/upload_attendee_csv.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    file = request.FILES.get('file')
    if form.is_valid():
        if file:
            reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
            next(reader)
            attendee_instance = Attendee()
            Attendee.objects.bulk_create(
                [Attendee(firstname=row[0],
                          surname=row[1],
                          email=row[2],
                          )
                 for row in reader])

            attendee_instance.save()

        return self.form_valid(form)

    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with this (cropped) section:

```
attendee_instance = Attendee()

Attendee.objects.bulk_create(
                [Attendee(firstname=row[0],
                          surname=row[1],
                          email=row[2],
                          )
attendee_instance.save()
```

With the first attendee_instance, you're creating a blank `Attendee` object.  You later save this blank object with `attendee_instance.save()`.

The line in the middle - `Attendee.objects.bulk_create...` - you're passing in a single item list to bulk_create, so it creates the object (with data) there. You don't need both.

What you want is probably:

```
Attendee.objects.create(firstname=row[0],
                          surname=row[1],
                          email=row[2],
                          )
```

You don't need the `bulk_create` unless you're creating more than one object, you can just use straight-up `create`.  Similarly, you don't need to create the object by `attendee_instance=Attendee()` and then manually change the attributes, when you can do it all in one go as described above.

It's worth noting the [caveats on the limitations of bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), particularly if you're not using Postgres, and also if you get to the point of using `post_save` and `pre_save` signals.  The [create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#create) method *does* trigger those save signals, so just make sure that you use the most appropriate one for your use case

Comment: Wow!! thanks a lot it worked like a charm. I removed saving of the instance and it all works. Looks like bulk_create does the saving of the instance it creates. Thanks a million.

Comment: Happy to help - and it does indeed do the save!  It's worth noting the [caveats on the limitations of bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create), particularly if you're not using Postgres, and also if you get to the point of using `post_save` and `pre_save` signals.  The [create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#create) method *does* trigger those save signals, so just make sure that you use the most appropriate one for your use case - I've updated the answer with those now, too.

Comment: Indeed, so much I have learnt from your proffesion advise. One more thing, in the same model I have a field named **author** and it is linked to the django **User** model via a **ForeignKey**. I wanted to instantiate and save the current user making the upload as the author, but I am getting an error of something like ```violating null constraints... not allowed``` but the object gets created and the author who is the current loged in user is instantiated in the database.

Comment: Plenty of [results on that one.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=django%20save%20model%20with%20foreign%20key).  I'll let you do your own reading there. :)

Comment: Attendee.objects.create(firstname=row[0],
                              surname=row[1],
                              email=row[2],
                              author=request.user,
                              )


Would I be doing something wrong here?

Comment: If you could accept the answer if it helped you, that'd be appreciated. :)

Comment: Sorry man, thanks a lot I rushed to using the solution you helped me with and forgot to click accept. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are initializing and saving an empty instance in addition to the `bulk_create`

```
 # This line shouldn't be needed
 attendee_instance = Attendee()
 Attendee.objects.bulk_create(
      [Attendee(firstname=row[0],
           surname=row[1],
           email=row[2],
       )
       for row in reader])

# Nor should this line.
attendee_instance.save()
```